# Do sectional charts indicate which runways have lighting installed?

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts, airport-lighting, chart-supplement

[KSFF](https://skyvector.com/airport/SFF/Felts-Field-Airport) has 3 runways (one in the water, two on land).

The sectional shows `*L` yet only 4L/22R has lights. Is there a trick on the sectional to tell which runway has lighting or do you have to look at the supplement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to tell which runway is lighted from the sectional chart.  You have to check the Chart Supplement. From the FAA [Chart Users' Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/) (27 January 2022) p. 16:

> The lighted runway may not be the longest runway available, and lights may not be illuminated along the full length of the runway. The Chart Supplement has a detailed description of airport and air navigation lighting aids for each airport.

Comment: @ymb1 - nice addition, thanks